# Good JAXB design pattern to wrap model and or convert model (POJO)?

Tags: design-patterns, jaxb

I have the following model

```
class MyClass {
    id
    someRandomString
}
```

I would like to return this POJO to the client as...

```
<Root>
    <random>if + randomstring</random>
</Root>
```

Basically I'm dealing with a very message oriented service so I need to wrap and transform the model to the outbound XML format... Same goes on the input side

I have this XML...

```
<Root>
    <Username>
    <Password>
    <Action> <-- Some action or service to perform
    <SomeModel1>
    <SomeModel2>
</Root>
```

So the root and username and password are constant elements while the SomeModel can change based on the "service"

Bassically i'm looking for a design-pattern where the XML doesn't match the model and there needs to be a transformation to and from...

Or what if I did...

```
class MyClass {
    id
    someRandomString
    random

    @XMLTransient
    getId()


    @XMLTransient
    getSomeRandomString()


    getRandom() {
        return id + someRandomString
    }
}
```

So JAXB will only map getRandom...

Another idea I have is create a bunch of classes that will represent the final output and just set the values to thoses...

So

```
class MyResponse {
    randomString
    status
    someOtherFieldRequired in response
}
```

and then I can do...

```
myResponse.setRandomString(myClass.getId() + myClass.getSomeRandomString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [XmlAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) in conjunction with [XmlJavaTypeAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html), but I think it might require you to encapsulate the id and someRandomString properties into a separate class. Spreading out an element value over two separate bean properties directly is not something I'd know how to do, if it is at all possible.

Comment: What if I added a get to the pojo that did the combine and only mapped that getter to the XML output?

Comment: You'll need a getter and setter to allow both marshalling and unmarshalling, but that's actually a really good idea. Make some getter/setter pair with a corresponding field that's never used (to make sure it's recognized as a bean property), and put logic in them to populate the two actual target fields, like some bait-and-switch. It's slightly hacky, but it could work!

Answer (score 1):

You could the `id` and `someRandomString` fields to separate elements and use a style sheet to combine the elements into one.  JAXB offers the `JAXBSource` class that fits it with the `javax.xml.transform` APIs:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.setId(123);
myClass.setSomeRandomString("FOO");

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("my-xslt.xml"));
Transformer t = tf.newTransformer(xslt);

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jc, myClass);

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

t.transform(source, result);
```