# JAXB convert multiple attributes to one type while unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, w3c, unmarshalling

Image I have an element like this `<someElement a="" b="" number="1" scale="meters"><child/></someElement>`

scale and number always appear together but they are not defined in one exclusive element.

When unmarshalling the `someElement` element to a `SomeElement` java instance I want a single member in the `SomeElement` class to represent `number` and `scale`.

At the moment both number and scale are attributes and then the `afterUnmarshall()` method is used for calculating one number.

Is there a way to do this without having the two member fields size and scale? Maybe with a `XmlAdapter`? How would I use this in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

MOXy offers the `@XmlTransformation` extension that allows you to represent a Java field/property as several XML nodes.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/xmltransformation-going-beyond.html

**UPDATE**

Alternatively you could use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case.  The adapter will we responsible for converting the single type representing number and scale (represented as FOO below) to a type with separate properties for number and scale.  You will still need to use the MOXy implementation to leverage the `@XmlPath` extension:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SomeElement {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String a;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String b;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NumberAndScaleAdapter.class)
    @XmlPath(".")
    private FOO numberAndScale;

    private Child child;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlAdapter
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: I'm using the reference implementation and only added the MOXy lib that allows me to use XmlReadTransformer.  But nothing is happening. Do I also have to use a XmlWriteTransformer or do I have to switch the entire JAXB processing to MOXy?

Comment: @FranzKafka - You will need to switch the JAXB provider for this app to be MOXy: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Can't you convince the JCP to actually make MOXy the RI? I sure wouldn't mind :D

Answer (score 1):

The answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896052/good-jaxb-design-pattern-to-wrap-model-and-or-convert-model-pojo) seem to correspond with what you're trying to do. Or at least some reverse of it. So you can either create a custom type that un/marshals using an XmlAdapter, or you can be mischievous with your getter/setter logic.