# Unmarshalling multiple XML elements to one field using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML file in format described below. I'm currently using JAXB to unmarshall the XML elements (`event`) to Java objects (`Event`). All properties work fine, except one...
As you can see in the XML, the `date` element stores **only** the date and the `time` stores **only** the time of the event. I would like to combine these two XML elements into one *LocalDataTime* field named `time`, with appropriate getters and setters.

*XML:*

```
...
<event>
    ...
    <date>2014-02-19</date>
    <time>2000-01-01T14:17:00Z</time>
    ...
</event>
...
```

*Desired Java Object:*

```
public class Event {
    ...
    // Returns a combination of the date and time stored in the XML
    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }
    ...
}
```

My first thought was to use a `XMLAdapter` but it seems that this only allows me to map 1 XML element to 1 Java object.

After that I tried to implement this by overriding the setters `setTime` and `setDate`. These setters would each just change the time or date of the stored time.. But I wasn't able to get it working and it also seemed a quite ugly way to do this.

I already read the following [JAXB convert multiple attributes to one type while unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936104/jaxb-convert-multiple-attributes-to-one-type-while-unmarshalling). But for this project, I would rather not use an external library like MOXy.

Does anyone know how to do this using solely JAXB in a *clean* way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define in your Event object lifecycle methods:

```
void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unm, Object parent) {
    localDateTime = ....
};
boolean beforeMarshal(Marshaller mar) {  
    date = localDateTime.toDate();
    ....
};
```

to construct the LocalDateTime property after unmarshalling (using the date and time values), and prepare date/time fields before marshalling using the current LocaLDateTime value. 
You would still need the time/date fields to match the xml and the localDateTime field must be XmlTransient. So it is not so different from the set/getter approach but probably more "clean".